# Nginx proxy_pass to node app not working rather looking in root path

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm trying to serve a static app and my node backend using this configuration. Site is loading fine but api call are not working. Instead of hitting the endpoint on localhost, it is looking for file in root path. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Here's my nginx configuration:

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;
   server_name www.domain.com;
   root /usr/share/nginx/html/dev/;

   # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
   if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
       return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
   }
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name www.domain.com;

   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.com/privkey.pem;

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }

   location /api/ {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_pass_request_headers on;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

In error log, the api call made appears like this:
`/usr/share/nginx/html/dev/api/api_path/index.html is not found`